# Order ggplot geom_point in order by date on X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-point

I have a table of maximum trip lengths by month which I am trying to graph in R ,
[image]
While trying to graph it, the X-axis does not graph according to the month, instead it graphs it alphabetically
[image]

I'm just getting started in R and I used the following code from what one of the videos I watched adjusted for my table names:

```
max_trips <- read.csv("max_and_min_trips.csv")

ggplot(data=max_trips)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=month,y=max_trip_duration))+
  scale_x_month(month_labels = "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: Check `str(max_trips)`, it's ordered alphabetically because your columns (both month and duration, guessimg from alignment to left on screenshot) are strings. You can try to switch from read.csv to readr:: read_csv to see if it can guess column types correctly for you.  For parsing dates  check `my()` (month-year) from lubridate - https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/reference/ymd.html

Comment: Please add reproducible data using `dput`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the data for your "month" column is stored as a vector of strings, not as a date.  In R, this data type is called a "character" (or `chr`).  You can confirm this by typing `class(max_trips$month)`.  The result is certainly `"character"` in your console.  Therefore, your solution would be to (1) convert the data type to a date and (2) adjust the formatting of the date on the x axis using `scale_x_date` and/or related functions.

I'll demonstrate the process with a simple example dataset and plot.  Here's the basic data frame and plot.  You'll see, the plot is again arranged "alphabetically" instead of as expected if the `mydf$dates` values were stored as dates in "month/year" format.

```
library(lubridate)
mydf <- data.frame(
  dates = c("1/21", "2/20", "12/21", "3/19", "10/19", "9/19"),
  yvals = c(13, 31, 14, 10, 20, 18))
ggplot(mydf, aes(x = dates, y = yvals)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

#### Convert to Date

To convert to a date, you can use a few different functions, but I find the `lubridate` package particularly useful here.  The `as_date()` function will be used for the conversion; however, we cannot just apply `as_date()` directly to `mydf$dates` or we will get the following error in the console:

```
> as_date(mydf$dates)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.
```

Since there are so many variety of ways you can format data which correspond to dates, date times, etc, we need to specify that our data is in "month/year" format.  The other key here is that data setup as a date must specify year, month *and day*.  Our data here is just specifying month and year, so we will first need to add a random "day" to each date before converting.  Here's something that works:

```
mydf$dates <- as_date(
  paste0("1/", mydf$dates),  # need to add a "day" to correctly format for date
  format = "%d/%m/%y"        # nomenclature from strptime()
)
```

The `paste0(...)` function serves to add `"1/"` before each value in `mydf$dates` and then the `format =` argument specifies the character values should be read as "day/month/year".  For more information on the nomenclature for formats of dates, see the help for the `strptime()` function [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/strptime).

Now our column is in date format:

```
> mydf$dates
[1] "2021-01-01" "2020-02-01" "2021-12-01" "2019-03-01" "2019-10-01" "2019-09-01"
> class(mydf$dates)
[1] "Date"
```

#### Changing Date Scale

When plotting now, the data is organized in the proper order along a date scale x axis.

```
p <- ggplot(mydf, aes(x = dates, y = yvals)) + geom_point()
p
```

[image]

If the labeling isn't quite what you are looking for, you may check the [documentation here](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) for the `scale_x_date()` function for some suggestions.  The basic idea is to setup the arguments for `breaks=` in your scale and how they are labeled with `date_labels=`.

```
p + scale_x_date(breaks="4 months", date_labels = "%m/%y")
```

[image]

In the OP's case, I would suggest the following code should work:

```
library(lubridate)

max_trips <- read.csv("max_and_min_trips.csv")
max_trips$month <- as_date(
  paste0("1/", max_trips$month),
  format = "%d/%m/%y")

ggplot(data=max_trips)+
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x=month,y=max_trip_duration))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", date_labels = "%Y-%m")
```